# ngAnimate does nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

My HTML looks like this;

```
  <div class="loadingmsg" ng-show="!isReady()" ng-animate="{show:'animate-show', hide:'animate-hide'}">
    <div class="loadingmsg-txt glyphicon glyphicon-flash">{{msg.loading || 'loading'}}</div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{msg.loadingPerc}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{msg.loadingPerc}}%;">
      {{msg.loadingPerc}}%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I've added the necessary classes to the CSS;

```
.animate-show, .animate-hide {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
    -o-transition:all linear 1s;
    transition:all linear 1s;
}

.animate-show {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-show.animate-show-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide.animate-hide-active {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Which is all quite simple.

But then, whenever `!isReady()` returns `true`, I'd like the `div` to fade out. That doesn't happen, there's absolutely no transition.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The new CSS:

```
.loadingmsg.ng-hide-add,
.loadingmsg.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 10s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 10s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 10s;
    -o-transition:all linear 10s;
    transition:all linear 10s;
}

.loadingmsg.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 0;
}

.loadingmsg.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
  <div class="loadingmsg" ng-show="!isReady()">
    <div class="loadingmsg-txt glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{msg.loadingPerc}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{msg.loadingPerc}}%;">
      {{msg.loadingPerc}}%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But that still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? Is it the latest one? (animation usage differs in version)

Comment: @callmekatootie `1.2.6`

Comment: Did you include `angular-animate.js`? -> `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>`

Comment: @Vucko I've tried that and it doesn't help. Also, as per the other answers, I don't really need to.

Comment: Hello, have you find a solution ? I have exactly the same problem... Thanks !

Comment: Hello @jeremieca, the answer posted below fixed my problem. I've also marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-animate` directive is deprecated since AngularJS 1.2.

Instead, you rely on the classes that are added by AngularJS when an element is shown or hidden.

Please see [this](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) excellent article on how to work with animations for AngularJS 1.2 onwards.

Your HTML markup remains the same with a minor edit - remove the `ng-animate` directive:

```
<div class="loadingmsg" ng-show="!isReady()">
    <div class="loadingmsg-txt glyphicon glyphicon-flash">
        {{msg.loading || 'loading'}}
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
             aria-valuenow="{{msg.loadingPerc}}" aria-valuemin="0" 
             aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{msg.loadingPerc}}%;">
            {{msg.loadingPerc}}%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You then define the appropriate animation for the respective classes (see reference)

```
.loadingmsg.ng-hide-add,
.loadingmsg.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
    -o-transition:all linear 1s;
    transition:all linear 1s;
}

.loadingmsg.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 0;
}

.loadingmsg.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 1;
}
```